# How to keep kivy CheckBox active after exiting the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, checkbox, kivy

i tried to make the question really simple with my example code. How to keep the value of checkbox even after i exiting the program? so when i re-open the program the checkbox will still be activated?

```
#Test.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox

class TestaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CheckBox()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestaApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the checkbox value in a file each time it changes with the ***on_checbox_active()*** callback. Then schedule another function to read this value on the first past of the eventloop with ***Clock.schedule_once(fun_name)***.

Comment: thanks but can you be more specific? like what type of file to store it and how to do it ?

Comment: check this out https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/